# How to store and access project settings in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-debugger

In my VS Code project I need to be able to reference (substitude) some common project constants from within `launch.json` and `tasks.json`.

My current solution is to put the variables in the `.vscode/settings.json` like this:

```
{ "MYVAR": "Foo" }
```

and then reference them via `${config:MYVAR}` from within e.g. `.vscode/tasks.json`. While this works, it creates a VS Code linter warning in `settings.json` saying "Unknown configuration setting".

So this makes me wondering: Is `settings.json` the right place to store such custom project config and if not, what would be the best place for this. I imagine something like an `.env` (dotenv) in my project whose entries can be referenced, but haven't found any docs on this.